# Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.3 not loading in Windows 10

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I've recently downloaded **Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.3** from Oracle [Website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html)
and this with **JDK** as well, but I tried to run in windows 10, it only goes 10% of progress bar, then disappeared. Can't run it at all?

**SQL Developer 4.1.3** can connect to **Oracle 11g db**, right?

Comment: I downloaded yesterday and connected to Oracle 11g2, on Windows 10.

Comment: It's 4.1.3 version? I have installed the Java SE SDK as well, but somehow, i can't get it running.....

Comment: Yes, 4.1.3. I did not install any Java SDK, but I had 4.0.2 installed previously. I just downloaded zip file, unzipped, and ran .exe file.

Comment: somehow, I managed to make it working. But I have to click sqldeveloper.exe for twice. strange enough.

Answer (score 1):

I've found 2 things most likely cause what you're experiencing:

1. video driver conflict with windows and Java - this is usually what happens to cause the program to just 'disappear.' If you open a CMD window, CD to your sqldeveloper\bin directory, and run the exe from there, you should see some sort of Java 'crash' stack when the GUI goes away suddenly. And in there, you'll see a reference to a windows dll that belongs to the video driver. if that's the case, update that driver, and you should be good
2. the application settings for your OS user are corrupted. To fix, find your AppData, Roaming Profiles folder for 'SQL Developer' - there should be a system4.1.3... folder in there - rename it, and restart sql developer.